# Issue with multidex, showing class not found in dexpathlist

Tags: android, crash, android-multidex

I am using Multidex in my app, which is causing some issue leading to unexpected crash of my app on opening it immediately after installing, it works fine when I run it through my android studio but when I try to install the app using my apk on some device it crashes, I thought it was something device specific, but it was crashing every time I used APK file to install on any device. I have tried many ways to fix the issue,

- I tried cleaning the project and building it again generating the apk
  and installing it, but did not work
- I tried invalidating cache and restarting android studio but still it din't work as well
- Then I started looking for a solution on the internet and I found many suggestions, i tried all of them. I went through various posts, blogs and documentations including [64K limit](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), [Multidex android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDex.html) and more...

my app's min sdk version is 16 so i did this,

```
defaultConfig {
    ......
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    .......
    multiDexEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    ........        
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary(true)

    // default scheme variables
    buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_SCHEME", "\"http\""
    buildConfigField "String", "REDIRECT_SCHEME", "\"https\""
}
```

I added this line to the dependencies,

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

I tried to understand and experimented a lot with the dexoptions in the gradle file,

```
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

I created a file named multidex.keep, the content of which is as follows:

```
android/support/multidex/BuildConfig/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V14/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V19/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex$V4/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDex/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor$1/class
android/support/multidex/MultiDexExtractor/class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil$CentralDirectory/class
android/support/multidex/ZipUtil/class
```

then i added these lines to the app's gradle file,

```
afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = []
    }
    dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    dx.additionalParameters += "--main-dex-      list=$projectDir/multidex.keep".toString()
}
}
```

I am still unable to fix the issue and still looking for the solution, any help/suggestions are welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please add the exception (including call trace) details.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?  I am having a similar crash...

Comment: I just updated my android studio and it stopped happening, I tried many ways, which worked only half of the time. Then I just updated my android studio, and I did not see that issue again!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in application tag of your manifest file :

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Comment: hey @R.R.M, I tried this on your suggestion, the app crashed when I ran it through android studio, immediately after installing the apk!

Comment: Can you post the stack trace so that I can understand why this is happening?